# Find the matrix of the given linear transformation with respect to the given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find the matrix of the linear transformation $T, T(x+iy)=x-iy$ with respect to the basis $B=(1+i, 1-i)$ This is from $\mathbb{C} $ to $\mathbb{C} $

So I do $T(1+i)=1-i$, and $T(1-i)=1+i$. How exactly do I make this look like

$\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$?

I need help with the steps along the way, please.

Edit:
The solutions manual lists this as the answer:
$\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad$
So I have $T(1+i)=1-i$, and $T(1-i)=1+i$.
I get from that $\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad [B]= \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad$

Where [B] has to equal $\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad$  Where did [B] come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are identifyng $\mathbb{C}$, as a vector space over the real numbers, with $\mathbb{R}^2$, so you  transformation acts as:
$$
T (x,y)^T \rightarrow (x,-y)^T
$$
so it is represented by the matrix
$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in the standard basis $\{(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T\}$.

In the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}=\{(1,1)^T,(1,-1)^T\}$ ( that is your basis $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ notation)
The transformation $T$ acts as a interchange of the vectors of the basis:
$$
Tv_1=v_2 \quad and \quad Tv_2=v_1
$$
so , in this basis, it is represented by the matrix:
$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I added information to my original question, what do you think?

Comment: I see.. and I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful . :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier is to identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ so your basis look like $B=[(1,1),(1,-1)]$ now you only have to make a change of basis and apply the linear transform